# How to display input field using button on-click function with Javascript/typescript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have created a button for adding contact details. When user clicks, few input fields should display to user like first name, last name.

How Can I do this?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: You should not use "onclick" html attribute. If you're using jquery, you should have a look at event listeners in javascript/jquery, it's easy to use... without your code or any example (http://jsfiddle.net) we can't really help...

Comment: Use jquery show and hide a div element method..

Comment: can anyone give code for typescript?

Answer (score 6):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/zewk17vL/).

It uses [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/) which makes it much easier.

Here is the snippet.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#fn").show();
  $("#ln").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click">
<br>
<div id="fn" hidden>First Name :
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<br>
<div id="ln" hidden>Last Name :
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try this..

HTML

```
 <input id="button" type="button" value="Click"><br>

 <div id="div_ctrl" hidden> 
   <div id="fn">First Name :<input type="text" id="txt1" /></div><br>
   <div id="ln">Last Name :<input type="text" id="txt2" /></div>

   <input id="button2" type="button" value="Submit" ><br>
 </div>       

 <div id="success" hidden>
    <div> Thank You.. Your Information is Saved Successfully! </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#button").click(function() {
$("#div_ctrl").show();
$("#success").hide();
$("#button").hide(); 
}); 

$("#button2").click(function() {
$("#success").show();
$("#div_ctrl").hide();
$("#button").hide(); 
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3pc55tk9/)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can only answer this from my assumptions. I'm assuming your input fields are not hidden, so may want to hide them first. Example style="display:none". Then in your onclick just do the following:

```
$("#buttonid").on("click", function(){
 $("#inputid").show();
```

});

Just a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to have a template for that:

```
var template = '<div><label for="fname">First Name:</label><input type="text" name="fname"><label for="lname">Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lname">';
```

After the template is done all you need is  to select your container or your last element and simply append the template

```
$('button').click(function(){
    // Code for container
    $('.container').append(template);
    // Code for last pair of elements
    $('.lastInputContainer').after(template);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad and you should add your code, but here is something:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/xt0d7bpa/)

HTML:

```
<button class="btn" >Click</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    $('.container').append('<input name="firstname" placeholder="Firt name"/>');
    $('.container').append('<input name="lastname" placeholder="Last name"/>');
});
```